# Tomcat 7 deployment fails. org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 not found

Tags: maven, tomcat, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a web application to a Tomcat 7 instance using the tomcat7-maven-plugin's tomcat7:deploy goal. However, it continuously fails to deploy, citing that:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64

All of the posts I've read suggest adding the Apache commons-codec to pom.xml. I have done that and it doesn't do a bit of good. I tried manually downloading the JAR and placing it in the WEB-INF/lib folder but that also had no effect.

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>edu.uta</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavAppoint</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MavAppoint Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.59</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>MavAppoint</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/MavAppoint</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have tried changing the scope for the commons-codec but nothing has worked so far. It's been driving me absolutely nuts! Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the "Run on Server" option in Eclipse to run the application instead of trying to deploy the application to the Tomcat installation on my computer.